# Twitter search for anything from a certain source

Tags: twitter

The [Twitter-search](http://search.twitter.com) features the possibility to search for a source of tweet by using the parameter "source:" (e.g. source:tweetdeck).

If I just search for that it complains about a missing query, but I actually want to search for any tweets from a certain source.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some form of criteria, even if it's just 'recent tweets'. To query every single tweet is, I suspect, not possible at all and certainly not within the capabilities of the API.

Note: My mistake - was thinking of one of the REST APIs.

Comment: That doesn't work. It still wants a query.
I tried different things like:
since:2010-09-14 source:tweetdeck

Comment: This one works without a query: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=near%3ANYC+within%3A15mi So perhaps you could just set a distance of miles equitable to the distance of the equator?

That said, will keep poking around.

Comment: You may have more success with one of the REST-ful APIs?

Comment: Currently I don't know yet if I'll even use in code.
I just want to know who tweets what with my app.

I tried within:10000mi but it returns:
Please provide a distance within 2500 kilometers.

Comment: Drat. Worth a shot. I've only got experience with REST API unfortunately. Whether or not it does what you want seems to be a case of trial and error. I guess the search API is rather the same... they do have different capabilities though - so don't rule out the other one.

Comment: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search says:
source: operator:

    results are limited to 7 days
    queries must contain at least one keyword parameter with the source: operator

That doesn't look good :/